# android soft keyboard spoils layout when appears

Tags: android, android-layout, android-softkeyboard

Here is a layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0px"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:background="#0000ff"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0px"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0px"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

I want blue bar to remain intact when EditText is touched and soft keyboard appears. I.e. I want its size and position to be preserved. I tried all four possible values for my activity's parameter `android:windowSoftInputMode` in the AndroidManifest. And always my blue bar moves or shrinks on soft keyboard appearing:

`android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustUnspecified"` or by default:

[image]

`android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` or `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"`:

[image]

`android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`:

[image]

Is it ever possible to keep it the same size and position when soft keyb appears?

Comment: I've tried with `adjustNothing` and it seems to work on my device (Google Nexus)

Answer (score 6):

you must use `<ScrollView>` as main layout.
example:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">
   ....
</ScrollView>
```

or use this code in AndroidManiFest.xml:

```
<activity
     android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing">
</activity>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the input is coming into an `EditText` of yours, it's always going to move something.

Consider having two layouts, one for when the keyboard is down, one for when the keyboard is up.

Using a `ViewSwitcher` may help with that.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because of the LinearLayout that you are using. Can you please change your inner layout with relative layout? In your current situation, keyboard just changes the margins between components because of the linear layout. And change your config with adjustNothing.